# Linux: copy files which are listed in a txt file from a directory (with subdirectories) to a specified folder

Tags: linux, batch-file, copy-paste

I have a txt file with only names of files in it. I.e. "999000 999008 999021" etc. They correspond to files that I have with the extension *.source I.e. 999000.source 999008.source 999021.source. These files exist within different sub-directories beneath a master directory. How would I go about copying the files listed in the txt file to another specified folder using commands in Linux?

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: Do you need to re-create the original directory structure in the destination directory?

Answer (score 2):

Provided there are no spaces in the file names:

```
(for fn in $(cat filenames.txt); do
    find "$master_dir" -type f -name "$fn.source"
done) |tar -cT - |(cd "$new_dir" && tar x)
```

Comment: You can avoid spawning an extra `cat` process in Bash: `for fn in $(<filenames.txt); do ...; done | tar cT - | tar xC "$new_dir"`

Comment: But tar would not copy xattrs, so it's down to `cp -a $(for fn in $(<filenames.txt); do find "$master_dir" -type f -name "$fn.source"
done) "$new_dir/";`.